# Error when edmx file is in a separate project

Tags: c#, string, entity-framework, connection

I have problem that says

> The specified named connection is either not found in the configuration, not intended to be used with the `EntityClient` provider, or not valid.

My edmx file is in separate project, but that project has connection string in its `app.config`

What could cause the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure the app.config is in the project which is set to be the startup project.

IF I understand correctly (I hope I do!):

You have two projects:

ApplicationServices (Startup Project)

- Web.config

EntityContainer

- MyEdmx.edmx
- App.config

When the project starts up, it reads from the web.config file.

You need to make sure the connection string is in the web.config file. I usually remove the app.config from the other projects if I do not plan on using them.

Also double check ApplicationServices project references EntityContainer.

Comment: it still does not work, start up project already has web config I have replaced connection string that was already there, I also tried to move all app config and still it does not work

Comment: Just to clarify - the connection string is in the web.config file?

Comment: yeah, I have two now ApplicationServices and EntityContainer

Comment: Ok, when you run your web application, it will only read the one config file for the startup project.