# Why context connection String isn't updated

Tags: mysql, entity-framework

I'm trying to connect my application to MySql using CodeFirst but I'm getting an error that's making me crazy with Context ConnectionString.

- Entity Framework 4.3.1
- MySql Connector 6.6.3

Web.config:

```
   <connectionStrings>
     <add name="PersonalContext" connectionString="server=localhost;UserId=root;password=1234;database=school;" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
   </connectionStrings>


  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
      <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL"  type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=6.6.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=852c9eb6525c1b53" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
```

Controller:

> var ctx = new SchoolContext();
>    ctx.Database.Initialize(true);

I would like to know why ctx.Connection.Connectionstring still with SQLEXPRESS

> "Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial
>   Catalog=MysqlTesting.Controllers.SchoolContext;Integrated
>   Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Application
>   Name=EntityFrameworkMUE"

I'm new with entityFramework and I would like to know what I'm doing wrong on my web.config.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4952269/entity-framework-problem-when-edmx-file-is-in-seperate-project)?

Comment: Hi Gert! thank's for your fast response! The ConnectionString is in the correct web.config ;) ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of your connection string either needs to match the name of the context class, or you need to tell your context class which connection string to use:

```
class SchoolContext
{
    public SchoolContext()
        : base("Name=PersonalContext")
    {
    }

    // DbSet properties here
}
```